# Encountering "NameError: name 'tryAgain' is not defined" error while executing Python web scraping code

Tags: python, compiler-errors

I'm attempting to scrape web pages using Python, and I'm encountering an error. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
from email import header
import random
import time
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

main_url = "http://www.google.com"

main_page_html = tryAgain(main_url)
main_page_soup = BeautifulSoup(main_page_html)

# Rest of the code to scrape data
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
  main_page_html  = tryAgain(main_url)
NameError: name 'tryAgain' is not defined
```

The tryAgain function is defined later in my code to handle scraping URLs with intermittent connection issues. Here's the tryAgain function:

```
def tryAgain(passed_url):
try:
    # Code to scrape the URL
except Exception:
    # Code to retry scraping after waiting
```

Why am I getting this error, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: You're trying to call `tryAgain` before it's defined.  Either define the function above the call, or else put the call inside a function that isn't called until after the `tryAgain` function definition.

Comment: For future questions, make sure you put the stack trace as text within the question, instead of an image - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20276330

Comment: Please remove the image of the error and replace it with text. Please rewrite the title so that describes the problem you are getting (putting some or all of the error in the title is normal). Note that Stack Overflow is not a chatroom.

Comment: I am new here and don't know how to ask a question here, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

You can think of it way that python in a opposite to some compiled languages, interprets things from top to bottom, line by line. So when it executes some line (it's a simplify but) only that is above it exists for python. Saying that, what would happen if you run this?

```
from email import header
import random
import time
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

main_url = "http://www.google.com"

main_page_html  = tryAgain(main_url)
```

Of course it says `tryAgain` is not defined! You need to move execution below the definition (or definition above the execution).

Comment: didn't get it, What are you trying to say??

Comment: What exactly you don't understand?

Comment: so how should I write to make it work, please once edit the code and tell

Answer (score 1):

Python is a scripting language. Always define your methods / classes before calling them.

When your code execution is on the following line

```
main_page_html  = tryAgain(main_url)
```

python cant find the the method "tryAgain" as it is defined later in the code.

Do this instead:

```
from email import header
import random
import time
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


# This is method that scrape URL and if it doesnt get scraped, waits for 20 seconds and then tries again. (I use it because my internet connection sometimes get disconnects)

def tryAgain(passed_url):
    try:
        page  = requests.get(passed_url).text
        return page
    except Exception:
        while 1:
            print("Trying again the URL:")
            print(passed_url)
            try:
                page  = requests.get(passed_url,headers = random.choice(header), timeout = timeout_time).text
                print("-------------------------------------")
                print("---- URL was successfully scraped ---")
                print("-------------------------------------")
                return page
            except Exception:
                time.sleep(20)
                continue 

main_url = "http://www.google.com"
main_page_html  = tryAgain(main_url)
main_page_soup = BeautifulSoup(main_page_html)

# Scrape all TDs from TRs inside Table
for tr in main_page_soup.select("table.class_of_table"):
   for td in tr.select("td#id"):
       print(td.text)
       # For acnhors inside TD
       print(td.select("a")[0].text)
       # Value of Href attribute
       print(td.select("a")[0]["href"])
```

Comment: this give me an error that  '''for tr in main_page_soup.select("table.class_of_table"):
NameError: name 'main_page_soup' is not defined'''

Comment: i have updated my answer. please check

Comment: It didn't work !